# Send updates with SignalR from multiple WebAPI projects

Tags: asp.net-web-api, signalr

Currently I have an MVC project and 2 WebAPI projects.

Is it possible to subscribe to events published from multiple WebAPI projects? I have this setup but I'm not sure if I'm this approach is correct. I am just using the example from http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-and-mvc - I'm not actually implementing a chat room, just researching what is possible.

I also seem to be getting a 404 when this happens @Scripts.Render("~/webapib/signalr/hubs)

URL Rewrite rules:

```
Project - URL               - Rewrite Url
WebAPIa - localhost/api     - http://localhost:81/{R:1}
WebAPIb - localhost/webapib - http://localhost:82/{R:1}
```

In _Layout:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jQuery/jquery.signalR-2.0.3.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/api/signalr/hubs)
@Scripts.Render("~/webapib/signalr/hubs)

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        // Declare a proxy to reference the hub.
        var chat = $.connection.chatHub;

        // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
        chat.client.broadcastMessage = function (name, message) {
            // do stuff
        };

        // define another hub connection here for 2nd WebAPI?
    });
</script>
```

In both WebAPI projects, each has its own controller with test method:

```
[HttpGet]
public void PublishTest(int _id)
{
    var clients = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ChatHub>().Clients;
    clients.All.broadcastMessage("name", "message");
}
```

In both WebAPI projects, each has its own OWIN start up class like so:

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(WebAPIa))]
namespace Random.Example.WebAPIa
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder _app)
        {
            _app.MapSignalR("/api/signalr", new HubConfiguration());
        }
    }
}

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(WebAPIb))]
namespace Random.Example.WebAPIb
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder _app)
        {
            _app.MapSignalR("/signalr", new HubConfiguration());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you made any progress on this issue? Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely try adding a second connection to the second server in the js file. Remember though that, because the `MVC` project  and the two `WebAPI` servers are on different ports, you must enable `CORS` support (install the `NuGet` package for `CORS` and enable cross origin calls on both `Startup.cs` files.

Have a look at this answer - [How to send message in cross domain using signalr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31793778/how-to-send-message-in-cross-domain-using-signalr/31803466#31803466)

Good luck!